# How to transform comma separated string into csv in mule?

Tags: csv, mule, mule-studio

I have a requirement where I have dynamic comma separated string value in a flow variable, which I need to convert into a **csv** file values.
for example, I can have following comma separated string values in variable:

```
abc,efg,ijk
```

or

```
mno,123,qrs,w3e
```

should be transferred into **csv** values like:

```
"abc","efg","ijk"
```

or

```
"mno","123","qrs","w3e"
```

I tried the following:

```
<set-variable variableName="stringValue" value="#['abc,efg,ijk']" doc:name="Variable"/>

  <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
       <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/csv header=true, quoteValues=true, quoteHeader=true
---
flowVars.stringValue splitBy ","]]></dw:set-payload>
 </dw:transform-message>
```

So, here I a expecting the **csv** file with value:

```
 "abc","efg","ijk"
```

But its not working , getting error!

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have already solved this, but if not - you're actually very close. The transformation to CSV expects a 2-dimensional array as input: an array of the lines for the file, where each line is an array of columns.

For example: `[["line1, Col1", "line1, Col2"], ["line2, col1", "line2, col2"], ... ]`.

After the **splitBy** in your example you only have a single array - `["abc","efg","ijk"]`, so the solution is to wrap that in an array: `[flowVars.stringValue splitBy ","]`. This gives the output you are looking for.